# Change tab on button click

Tags: c#

Does anybody know  how to move to a different tab when you click a button? Is there a general statement?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I know that something needs to be entered into the method above but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by _move to a different tab_? What is moving exactly?

Comment: Start on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or google, and show what you have tried, what language you are using, what framework...

Comment: I want it to change tab. I am using tab control and have 3 tabs and I would like to jump to a different tab when I click a button

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: and use in Ckik Button >> TabItem.SelectedIndex(0), 1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = DesiredTabPage;
```

DesiredTabPage is the name of the tabPage you want to move to it

Comment: Thank you for getting straight to the point! I knew my question was simple! Thanks a lot